# Large "Cached App Process" in simple android app. Is this a concern?

Tags: java, android

I've written an android application for tee time reservations at a single golf course.

When I look at the "cached app processes" under "running apps" (galaxy nexus running ics) I see that the cached process for my app is 47mb (which is the most of ANY app, the second being gmail at 44mb).

Is this something I should be concerned about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not be afraid that your process is cached.

The fact that your process is 47MB may be a concern, insofar as that you can't have a process that big on any Android devices. Now, if the space is being taken up with cached content, using stuff like `SoftReferences`, then the size may be fine -- older devices with smaller heaps will eject stuff from the cache more quickly.